# Load environment properties before @Configuration class loads?

Tags: spring-boot

I am facing problem while configuring SSL related env. properties in my SpringBoot application. Following are the properties

```
server.ssl.key-store=XXXX
server.ssl.key-password=XXXX
server.ssl.trust-store=XXXX
```

Above properties are used by ActiveMQ to secure the connection. Following is the sample code

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(this.useAsyncSend);
        connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(this.alwaysSessionAsync);
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledge(this.optimizeAcknowledge);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(this.Username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(this.password);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

But above code unable to create SSL connection instead ending up with TCP connection with the ActiveMQ. So I change the code little bit to debug the problem

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "broker.ks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "XXXXX");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "client.ts");
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(this.useAsyncSend);
        connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(this.alwaysSessionAsync);
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledge(this.optimizeAcknowledge);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(this.Username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(this.password);
        return connectionFactory;
   }
```

And then it started working fine. It is able to make SSL connection between client and server. So I came to conclusion that the properties that contains in application.properties file are loading after the @Configuarion class load.
So my query is "**is it possible to load these env. related properties before the DispatchcherServlet start loading all the Configuration classes?**"

Comment: properties that contains in application.properties file are loading after the @Configuarion class load ----- >  This is not true

Comment: I agree and I do believe so. But how the code is running for 2nd case?

Comment: Is there a way to tell SpringBoot to load the properties that taken care by spring itself to be load before any other properties?